# TFS code analysis for java/maven projects

Tags: maven, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I have a brand new TFS2018 test installation and try to run a maven build with sonarqube analysis.

The sonarqube extension is installed from the marketplace and configured to use our internal Sonarqube. I added the prepare and publish SonarQube steps to my build like described.
[image: Build Steps]
In the prepare step I can successfully select my SonarQube endpoint from the drop down box.
[image: Prepare analysis on SonarQube configuration]
When I now tick the "Use SonarQube" check box in my maven task the SonarQube-Endpoint drop-down box is empty. My SonarQube-Server "Heuboe" does not show up. Even if I type it in the box stays invalid.

Any hint what's going wrong? Does anybody now how to file an issue to SonarQube directly. I can view issues under: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VSTS/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel

but I didn't find a way to report one.

Comment: Do you solve it with a Generic Endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven task is expecting a **Generic Endpoint**. The SonarQube extension adds another type of endpoint specifically for SonarQube, which the built-in Maven task has no awareness of.

Version 2.* of the task (which should be selectable from the dropdown menu for the task) has another method of running SonarQube, which **will** use the endpoint defined in the *Prepare Analysis* step.

Comment: Only find 1.* in my version dropdown menu. Do I have to install another maven task ?

Comment: @JayBee No, just create a Generic Endpoint for SonarQube, then choose it in Maven task.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT If I create a Generic Endpoint I can't choose it in the Prepare analysis on SonarQube task.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT ok, I remove all SonarQube-Tasks and just used the Maven check box with an generic endpoint. Analysis and reporting works. Fine.
Thx !